# How to spin image of wheel continuously in c++ using C++ Builder?

Tags: c++, c++builder

I am trying to rotate an image of wheel continuously. I was able to rotate the wheel for once only. But I want that wheel to rotate continuously. Need help.
Here is the code:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
  int angle = 45; //45° for example
  Graphics::TBitmap *SrcBitmap = new Graphics::TBitmap;
  Graphics::TBitmap *DestBitmap = new Graphics::TBitmap;
  SrcBitmap->LoadFromFile("image1.bmp");
  //Convert degrees to radians
  float radians = (2*3.1416*angle)/360;

  float cosine = (float)cos(radians);
  float sine   = (float)sin(radians);

  float Point1x = (-SrcBitmap->Height*sine);
  float Point1y = (SrcBitmap->Height*cosine);
  float Point2x = (SrcBitmap->Width*cosine-SrcBitmap->Height*sine);
  float Point2y = (SrcBitmap->Height*cosine+SrcBitmap->Width*sine);
  float Point3x = (SrcBitmap->Width*cosine);
  float Point3y = (SrcBitmap->Width*sine);

  float minx = min(0,min(Point1x,min(Point2x,Point3x)));
  float miny = min(0,min(Point1y,min(Point2y,Point3y)));
  float maxx = max(Point1x,max(Point2x,Point3x));
  float maxy = max(Point1y,max(Point2y,Point3y));

  int DestBitmapWidth  = (int)ceil(fabs(maxx)-minx);
  int DestBitmapHeight = (int)ceil(fabs(maxy)-miny);

  DestBitmap->Height = DestBitmapHeight;
  DestBitmap->Width  = DestBitmapWidth;
  Form1->Refresh();

  for (int x=0; x < DestBitmapWidth; x++)
  {
    for (int y=0; y < DestBitmapHeight; y++)
    {
      int SrcBitmapx = (int)((x+minx)*cosine+(y+miny)*sine);
      int SrcBitmapy = (int)((y+miny)*cosine-(x+minx)*sine);

      if (SrcBitmapx >=0 && SrcBitmapx < SrcBitmap->Width 
          && SrcBitmapy >=0 && SrcBitmapy < SrcBitmap->Height)
      {
        DestBitmap->Canvas->Pixels[x][y] = 
        SrcBitmap->Canvas->Pixels[SrcBitmapx][SrcBitmapy];
      }
    }
  }

  //Show the rotated bitmap
  Image1->Picture->Bitmap=DestBitmap;
  delete DestBitmap;
  delete SrcBitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get it right you have a wheel image in image1.bmp file and you want to rotate it continuously. First of all, it seems you put your rotation code into a click event! Events are user triggered events and are not good for continuous behaviour. It is common to use them as triggers for some actions..In this case for example maybe starting the continuous rotation behaviour and stopping it.

If we move to you code, at the beginning you create input and output bitmaps.

```
Graphics::TBitmap *SrcBitmap = new Graphics::TBitmap;
Graphics::TBitmap *DestBitmap = new Graphics::TBitmap;
```

and loading the input from an external source file (which stands intact!!)

```
SrcBitmap->LoadFromFile("image1.bmp");
```

then your code rotates TImage object and then rotates each pixel...Then sets the results to the output bitmap which is an dynamic Timage Object...
Since your source pixels are not changing continously, You always start with the same data and endup with the same result!

My suggestion is to load the image object before your continous rotation starts(forexample during the Form.Show) then revise your code as starts with a bitmap created from TImage object(which was loaded at the Form.Show) and flushs output back to that bitmap. Like summing an array of integers to summation variable:

```
int sum = 0 
for(int i=0;i<ListSize;i++)
 sum = sum+List[i];
```

Possibly, after your revisions, you can not get a proper rotating behaviour..you may use timers to handle the frequency of the rotation triggering so that you get contiously rotating wheel..